# javascript sort list of objects containing song titles alphabetically

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a list of objects in javascript where the 'name' key has a string value of a song title, I'm trying to sort this list in order of the 'name' fields so the titles appear in alphabetical order, I have a semi working solution but it isn't looking at the 'name' field and I'm not sure how to fix that?

```js
  var files = [
  {'name':"1. Pit om Akhshav Pit om Hayom"}, 
  {'name':'2. Rabbi Akiva'}, 
  {'name': '4. Kochavim Ba Dli'}, 
  {'name': '3. Yaldut'}, 
  {'name': '5. Simlat Klulot'}, 
  {'name': '12. Yaldi Enenu Yeled'},
  {'name': '6. Mayim Le David'}, 
  {'name': '7. Ahava Shel Tereza De Mon'}, 
  {'name': '8. Ba Ir Ha Zu Shalom'}, 
  {'name': '9. Ahavat Kayits'}, 
  {'name': '10. Tirza Yafa'}, 
  {'name': '11. Im Tevakshi'},
  ]

const sorted = Object.entries(files)
  .sort((a, b) => b[1].active - a[1].active)
  .reduce((r, [key, value]) => {
    r[key] = value
    return r
  }, {})

  console.log('sorted = ', sorted)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do yo expect? I mean, may you show how is the final object sorted?

Answer (score 2):

Updated my answer to sort numerically, than alpha

```
    var files = [
  {'name':"1. Pit om Akhshav Pit om Hayom"}, 
  {'name':'2. Rabbi Akiva'}, 
  {'name': '4. Kochavim Ba Dli'}, 
  {'name': '3. Yaldut'}, 
  {'name': '5. Simlat Klulot'}, 
  {'name': '12. Yaldi Enenu Yeled'},
  {'name': '6. Mayim Le David'}, 
  {'name': '7. Ahava Shel Tereza De Mon'}, 
  {'name': '8. Ba Ir Ha Zu Shalom'}, 
  {'name': '9. Ahavat Kayits'}, 
  {'name': '10. Tirza Yafa'}, 
  {'name': '11. Im Tevakshi'},
  ];


files.sort((a, b) => (parseInt(a.name.split('.')[0]) > parseInt(b.name.split('.')[0])) ? 1 : (a.name.split('.')[1] === b.name.split('.')[1]) ? ((parseInt(a.name.split('.')[0]) > parseInt(b.name.split('.')[0])) ? 1 : -1) : -1 )
console.log(files);
```

Comment: i need to look at the numerical value first if it exists (assuming it does in this case, and that the list will always start with a number and a period followed by a space and a string)

Comment: i see, i understand your requirement better now

Answer (score 1):

`files` is not an object. `Object.entries` doesn't work as you expected.

If you want to sort numerically first and then sort alphabetically, you need to split names and compare.

```js
var files = [
  {'name':"1. Pit om Akhshav Pit om Hayom"}, 
  {'name':'2. Rabbi Akiva'}, 
  {'name': '4. Kochavim Ba Dli'}, 
  {'name': '3. Yaldut'}, 
  {'name': '5. Simlat Klulot'}, 
  {'name': '12. Yaldi Enenu Yeled'},
  {'name': '6. Mayim Le David'}, 
  {'name': '7. Ahava Shel Tereza De Mon'}, 
  {'name': '8. Ba Ir Ha Zu Shalom'}, 
  {'name': '9. Ahavat Kayits'}, 
  {'name': '10. Tirza Yafa'}, 
  {'name': '11. Im Tevakshi'},
  ]

files.sort((a,b) => {
  const [aNum, aStr] = a.name.split('. ');
  const [bNum, bStr] = b.name.split('. ');
  
  return aNum - bNum || aStr.localeCompare(bStr);
});
console.log('sorted = ', files);
```